# Accessing FMCSA QCMobile API

Tags: api

I'm building a web application that needs to search the QCMobile API using the URL endpoint their documentation provided.

API URL

The path for all API resources must start with: https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/ The following are the Endpoints

EndPoint Name   Query Parameters    Example
/carriers/docketNumber/:docketNumber/       /carriers/docketNumber/1515?webKey=jk+k...

My URL is: 
https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/docketNumber/402573?webKey=1a7649929fa2....

But I get this json response: 
{"links":[],"content":"There is no resource for path /qc/services/carriers/docketNumber/402573"}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the endpoint name listed on the specs page isn't correct for docketNumber.  I tried your link with my webkey and it didn't work for me either.  I replaced "docketNumber" with "docket-number" and I got a complete response.

https://mobile.fmcsa.dot.gov/qc/services/carriers/docket-number/402573.xml?webKey=xxxxx

Comment: Hi there.  I tried the endpoint with my webKey and got the correct response.  I would not have considered using "docket-number", but thanks.  Spent weeks on that. A big headache!!!